# Remove the trailing ICON and the space assigned for Trailing ICON from the Expansion Tile

Tags: flutter, dart, expansion-tile

I am using a Expansion tile, but I do not want to have any trailing space occupied at the end of the widget. Event though i remove the trailing ICON with sized box, still the space for the ICON is occupied, I do not want the entire space for the content rather then the trailing ICON.

Below is my code:

```
ExpansionTile(
      initiallyExpanded: expanded,
      trailing: const SizedBox.shrink(),
      textColor: Colors.teal,
      collapsedTextColor: Colors.teal,
      title: SingleChildScrollView(
          scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
          child: Center(
              child: Text(title,
                  style: const TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.teal,
                  )))),
      iconColor: Colors.green,
      collapsedIconColor: Colors.teal,
      children: body)
```

Below is the image:

[image: Expansion Tile]

Comment: Can you share an example of what you want to achieve?

Comment: @tomerpacific
I want the entire space to be occupied by the content in the left side and completely hide the trailing ICON and the highlighted whitespace.

Comment: So if I understand correctly, you don't want the pointing down arrow to show at all? Meaning, the text should take the entire space of the tile?

Comment: Why not just use a ListTile instead if you don't need the arrow icon orelse you have to customise your own Expansion Tile.

Comment: @tomerpacific , Yes.. you are correct.

Answer (score -1):

As per your desired behavior, you can just use a [ListTile](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ListTile-class.html):

```
ListTile(
      trailing: const SizedBox.shrink(),
      textColor: Colors.teal,
      title: SingleChildScrollView(
          scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
          child: Center(
              child: Text(title,
                  style: const TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.teal,
                  )
               )
            )
      ),
      children: body)
```

***Note: You might need to wrap the ListTile inside of an Expanded widget if it is within a Row/Column***

Comment: , I need an expansion tile , because I have more content to display when it is expanded.

Comment: As per the [expansion tile documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ExpansionTile-class.html) it comes built in with the arrow. You can't have it both ways. Meaning, have a tile that will expand when more content is available and not have the arrow. You can create your own ListTile with your desired behavior.